# Dataflow Job - HTTP 400 Non Empty Data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I launched a dataflow batch job to load csv data from GCS to Pubsub.

Dataflow job is failing with the following log portion:

> Error message from worker: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: **400 Bad Request { "code" : 400, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "One or more messages in the publish request is empty. Each message must contain either non-empty data, or at least one attribute.", "reason" : "badRequest" } ], "message" : "One or more messages in the publish request is empty. Each message must contain either non-empty data, or at least one attribute.", "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT" }** com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150) com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113) com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40) com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:443) com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1108) com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:541) com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:474) com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:591) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubJsonClient.publish(PubsubJsonClient.java:138) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO$Write$PubsubBoundedWriter.publish(PubsubIO.java:1195) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO$Write$PubsubBoundedWriter.finishBundle(PubsubIO.java:1184)

So basically it's saying that there is at least on line empty but the csv data contains some empty fields but not a full empty line

here is a sample below

2019-12-01 00:00:00 UTC,remove_from_cart,5712790,1487580005268456287,,f.o.x,6.27,576802932,51d85cb0-897f-48d2-918b-ad63965c12dc

2019-12-01 00:00:00 UTC,view,5764655,1487580005411062629,,cnd,29.05,412120092,8adff31e-2051-4894-9758-224bfa8aec18

2019-12-01 00:00:02 UTC,cart,4958,1487580009471148064,,runail,1.19,494077766,c99a50e8-2fac-4c4d-89ec-41c05f114554

2019-12-01 00:00:05 UTC,view,5848413,1487580007675986893,,freedecor,0.79,348405118,722ffea5-73c0-4924-8e8f-371ff8031af4

2019-12-01 00:00:07 UTC,view,5824148,1487580005511725929,,,5.56,576005683,28172809-7e4a-45ce-bab0-5efa90117cd5

2019-12-01 00:00:09 UTC,view,5773361,1487580005134238553,,runail,2.62,560109803,38cf4ba1-4a0a-4c9e-b870-46685d105f95

2019-12-01 00:00:18 UTC,cart,5629988,1487580009311764506,,,1.19,579966747,1512be50-d0fd-4a92-bcd8-3ea3943f2a3b

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: Those errors are hard to spot. Try adding a DoFn before pubsub that filters the input first and has two utputs (main -> that goes to pubsub and 'error' -> that writes to a file in GCP).

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code / add skeleton code here?

Comment: Hi, it's based on the default gcs to pubsub template.The issue was the csv data itself on some specific chuncks. I used different ones and it's working. thank you for your support.

Comment: @MnR, I am glad you found the cause of the issue. Please go ahead and post the steps you took as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Yes of course. so basically i took an other chunk of the data itself and transformed it to JSON (since from PubSub it will be streamed to BigQuery). that's it.